# curl POST request empty in ZF2 Rest API

Tags: post, curl, zend-framework2

I am testing my ZF2 Rest Module that is running on localhost, by sending curl POST requests from the same box.

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: Application/json" -d '{username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}' http://localhost/api/login
```

In the corresponding controller and action, I have tried returning the POST parameters, but an empty array is returned always

```
var_dump($this->getRequest()); // returns:  array(0){}
var_dump($_POST);              // returns:  array(0){}
```

If I switch from POST to GET with

```
curl -i -G -H "Content-Type: Application/json" -d '{username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}' http://localhost/api/login
```

it actually seems to work

```
var_dump($_GET); // returns: array(1) {["{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}"]=>string(0) ""}
```

Why is the POST request failing to pass/extract the parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP only populates `$_POST` for form urlencoded POST data. You've explicitly set the content type to JSON, so the PHP way to access this would be:

```
file_get_contents("php://input");
```

In ZF2, I believe you want:

```
$this->getRequest()->getContent();
```

and in practice, you'll probably want to run this through `json_decode()`.

Comment: came to this solution myself but you are 100% right. That was the problem